# How to add a string to a list without duplicates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, list, duplicates

I do not know how to check if my variable or it duplicate are already in the list before adding it.

Let's take an example of a list:

`LIST = ['TestA', 'TestB', 'TestC (AZE)', 'TestB (#2)']`

- If I want to add '**TestA**', then I add '**TestA (#2)**'.
- If I want to add '**TestB**' or '**TestB (#X)**', where `X` is any number,
  then I add '**TestB (#3)**' because a duplicate is already present and the duplicate number will be **3**.
- If I want to add '**TestC (AZE)**', then I add '**TestC (AZE) (#2)**'.

I started doing this:

```
VARIABLE = "TestB"

if(this.LIST.includes(VARIABLE)) {
    this.LIST.push(VARIABLE + " (#2)");
} else {
    this.LIST.push(VARIABLE);
}
```

The problem is that if I add "**TestB**" several times, several "**TestB (#2)**" will be added.

If anyone can help me put this into practice, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another object to keep track of the number of times each string has occurred so far:

```js
LIST = [];

const counts = {};
function addToList(item) {
  counts[item] = (counts[item] || 0) + 1;
  LIST.push(item + (counts[item] === 1 ? '' : ' (#' + counts[item] + ')'));
}

addToList('foo');
addToList('foo');
addToList('bar');
addToList('baz');
addToList('bar');
addToList('foo');
console.log(LIST);
```

Either make sure `addToList` is not called with a `(#` suffix, or strip out `(#` suffixes first, eg:

```js
LIST = [];

const counts = {};
function addToList(item) {
  const trailingMatch = item.match(/ \(#\d+\)$/);
  if (trailingMatch) {
    item = item.slice(0, item.length - trailingMatch[0].length);
  }
  counts[item] = (counts[item] || 0) + 1;
  LIST.push(item + (counts[item] === 1 ? '' : ' (#' + counts[item] + ')'));
}

addToList('foo');
addToList('foo');
addToList('bar');
addToList('baz');
addToList('bar');
addToList('foo');
addToList('foo (#2)');
console.log(LIST);
```

Comment: But if I add "foo (#2)" there will be a duplicate

Comment: When passing an item to `addToList`, always pass it *without* the numeric suffix - let `addToList` take care of it instead.

Comment: In my case the variable comes from an input and it is possible that a user could use a suffix, I will see if I can use a regex validator on the input

Comment: It's pretty simple, just need `/ \(#\d+\)$/` and then slice it off if there's a match

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

- Get the key from the passed value to be added,
- Reverse the list and find the first occurrence of matching key
- Get the digit out of key, if digit is present add 1 to it else set it as `2`
- If key is not find add the value itself to list

```js
let LIST = ['TestA', 'TestB', 'TestC (AZE)', 'TestB (#2)']

let adder = (val) => {
  let key = val.replace(/^(.*)\(#\d+\)$/g, '$1').trim()
  let findValue = [...LIST].reverse().find(v => v.includes(key))
  if (findValue) {
    let [_, digit] = (findValue.match(/^.*\s\(#(\d+)\)/) || [0, 0])
    if (digit) {
      LIST.push(key + ` (#${+digit+1})`)
    } else {
      LIST.push(key + ` (#${2})`)
    }
  } else {
    LIST.push(val)
  }
}

adder("TestA")
console.log(LIST)

adder("TestC (AZE)")
console.log(LIST)

adder("TestZ")
console.log(LIST)

adder("TestRandom (23)")
console.log(LIST)

adder("TestRandom (23)")
console.log(LIST)
```

Comment: @Quentin no worries always happy to help :)